# How to get profile information from google+ login android?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I have started integrating the google+ login in my project by referring this link https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in?configured.  Now i have enabled the Google+ API in developer console and configured sha1 certificate and downloaded the configuration(google-services.json) file and pasted in app module of my project.

After executing the app, i am able to login (connect) successfully. And the  onConncected() function also called. Now i have used the following code to retrieve the profile information

```
  @Override
public void onConnected() {

  if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
    Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
    String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
    String personPhoto = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
    String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
  }
}
```

But getCurrentPerson() always throws null. i am getting following error in my logcat

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
```

i referred these links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212725/why-does-plusclient-loadpeople-fail-with-http-403-error),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843593/getting-user-credentials-using-google-api) to resolve the issue. but the result always throws null.

i am connecting ApiClient by using following code

```
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
            .build();
```

I am able to get the connected email successfully by  `Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);` but not able to get the profile information.

Did i missed anything in my code? 
Could anybody help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled google + api then create client id for your app with sha1 og your editor.I hope it will work.. and initialize googleApiClient as below

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(LoginActivity.this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. how to create the client id? and where do we use this?

Comment: it is not used in app but its must . Google develer console->add credentail->0 Auth 2.0 client id and provide your sha1

Comment: let me know if face any problem

Comment: Hi i tried , i am getting this exception,  "Duplicate fingerprint
The fingerprint you specified is already used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project"

Comment: mention your exception

Comment: The fingerprint you specified is already used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project

Comment: Solution is to delete the project that is using that SHA1 in console.developers.google.com for the old/incorrect project.

You cannot change the SHA1 fingerprint once it is set. Remember that deleting the project takes 7 days to completely remove it.

Another option is to delete the debug.keystore and generate a new one with:

keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey
-storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -validity 14000
Remember you have to uninstall the app otherwise you get the [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE] error.

Comment: ok i will try with  release keystore's sha1 instead of using debug keystore.

Comment: i am getting the same exception while giving new keystore's sha1. because given sha1 certificate is already configured and then only i can get the json file.

Comment: i think you should change project name in editor and console and with new package name

Comment: and second possible solution is check with release sha1

Comment: i have changed the project name also. but negative result.

Comment: from my side its last solution . You should  try to change console account means login with other account and creat project properly